# PHP/SQL - How can I filter out a record that has a clash with another table's data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a search room query that searches for available rooms based on user input; number of beds, check in date and check out date. The current code works to search rooms based on the number of beds but it cannot filter out rooms with existing bookings whose date range overlap with the user input's dates. This is the current code:

```
$sql = "SELECT rooms.rid, beds, orientation, price FROM rooms 
        WHERE beds = $nOfBeds AND rooms.rid NOT IN 
                (SELECT bookings.rid FROM bookings 
                 WHERE $cInDate BETWEEN checkin AND checkout OR 
                ($cInDate <= checkin AND $cOutDate >= checkout))";

if ($rOrientation != "") {
$sql .= " AND orientation = '$rOrientation'";
}

$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error($conn));
```

this is my bookings table:
 [image: picture]

this is my rooms table:

[image: pic2]

Comment: You need to rethink your table structure. What if a booking has more than one room?

Comment: Also, what if a property wants to modify its pricing based on number of people or number of nights?

Answer (score 0):

```
($cInDate <= checkin AND $cOutDate >= checkout)
```

is flawed as it only restricts a longer stay.

You could replace it by:

```
($cInDate <= checkin AND $cOutDate >= checkin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Julie Pelletier is right, that the where clause on checkin and checkout date is flawed. But there is a better way to fix it.

You need all those bookings that do not lie in the window specified by the user. So, if you can make the following assumptions:

- User input $cInDate <= $cOutDate
- In your database, checkin <= checkout, for all rows

Then, all you need is the following query:

```
WHERE ($cOutDate < checkin OR $cInDate > checkout)
```

Also, in your inner query, you might want to change `SELECT bookings.rid FROM bookings` to `SELECT DISTINCT bookings.rid FROM bookings` to optimize the `IN` clause on it.